# Segmentation Fault in C function desired to edit a node in a Linked List, as well as Alphabetizing the List itself

Tags: c, function, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have been tasked with writing a function that must edit a node in a linked list. I have the following code so far that seems to be somewhat working, but there are still some problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct flavor {
    char *name;
    int available;
    struct flavor *next;
};

// "Head" node
struct flavor *first = NULL;
// Current node
struct flavor *current = NULL;

void insert(char *name, int available) {
    struct flavor *node = (struct flavor*)malloc(sizeof(struct flavor));

    node->name = name;
    node->available = available;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (first == NULL) {
        first = node;
        return;
    }

    current = first;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = node;
}

void sort(struct flavor *first) {
    char *i;

    struct flavor *temp1;
    struct flavor *temp2;

    for (temp1 = first; temp1 != NULL; temp1 = temp1->next) {
        for (temp2 = temp1->next; temp2 != NULL; temp2 = temp2->next) {
            if (temp2->name < temp1->name) {
                i = temp1->name;
                temp1->name = temp2->name;
                temp2->name = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

void display() {
    struct flavor *ptr = first;

    printf("Available shake flavors\n");

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("\nName: %s\n", ptr->name);
        printf("Available: %d\n", ptr->available);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

struct flavor *edit_flavor(struct flavor *first, char *old_name, char *new_name) {

    if (first == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty");
        return;
    }

    current = first;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        if (current->name == old_name) {
            current->name = new_name;
            printf("\nFlavor %s replaced with %lu\n", old_name, new_name);
            return;
        }

        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("\n%s does not exist in the list\n", old_name);
}

int main(void) {

    char *old = "";
    char *new = "";

    insert("Banana", 1);
    insert("Mango", 0);
    insert("Strawberry", 1);
    insert("Apple", 1);

    sort(first);
    display();
    printf("\nPlease enter old flavor: ");
    scanf("%s", &old);
    printf("Please enter new name: ");
    scanf("%s", &new);
    edit_flavor(first, old, new);
    sort(first);
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to use the program at all, I keep getting the error `segmentation fault (core dumped)` and I am not sure what I have done wrong?

On top of that, my insert into the "Linked List" seems to be working just fine, but I need the list to be in alphabetical order and it also needs to be updated in alphabetical order once a node has been edited. I have attempted to implement the `sort()` function, but it is not working at all and I think it may be due to the fact that I'm not comparing the names correctly (as they are strings?). How can I fix the sort function in order to correctly alphabetize the list?

Comment: It's not clear what `edit_flavor` is supposed to do. If it's only supposed to replace the old flavor with the new flavor and not do anything else, then it must return `void`. If it's supposed to do something else, what?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That makes more sense, and like I said once I change it to void, the warnings disappear. It doesn't however change the initial Segmentation Fault error, and I am wondering if that is being caused by me not handling variable types correctly with scanf and maybe printf?

Comment: You're definitely not handling `old` or `new` correctly. Both of them are initialized as pointers to literal string constants. By definition, constants can't be modified. Then it seems like you're trying to use `scanf` to modify them. If so, why point them to constant literals?

Comment: Think about it this way: After you call `edit_flavor`, the entry that holds the new flavor has to have a pointer to a string that was allocated somewhere. Where is space to hold that string allocated? The answer is nowhere -- your code never allocates any memory to hold the entered string in, so the `name` pointer has nothing to point to.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, do not use global variables such as `first` and `current`.

The function interface is inconsistent. For example the function `edit_flavo`, on the one hand, accepts the head node first through its first parameter. On the other hand, it uses the global variable `current`.

The function `sort` is incorrect. It does not swap values of the data member `available`. This comparison in the if statement

```
if (temp2->name < temp1->name) {
```

does not make sense because there are compared addresses of string literals instead of comparing the pointed string literals themselves using the C string function `strcmp`.

The list should not keeps addresses of string literals but it should make copies of passed strings in a dynamically allocated memory.

And it will be more correct to swap entire nodes in the sort function instead of swapping data members of pointed nodes.

In function `edit_flavor` this if statement

```
if (current->name == old_name) {
```

in general also is incorrect. Whether equal string literals are stored by the compiler as separate character arrays or as a one array depends on the a compiler options. So it is not necessary that for example the condition in such an if statement

```
if ( "Hello" == "Hello" )
```

will yield true. Again you need to use the C standard string function `strcmp` to compare pointed string literals.

In Main you declared two pointers to string literals.

```
char *old = "";
char *new = "";
```

You may not change string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. You need to declare character arrays where the strings entered by the user will be stored. So one more the list shall store deep copes of strings not their addresses.

These statements

```
scanf("%s", &old);
scanf("%s", &new);
```

are incorrect. Firstly the argument expressions shall have the type `char *`  as the type of variables `old` and `new` instead of the type `char **` that the expressions `&old` and `&new` have. And secondly such a call invokes undefined behavior because the function `scanf` will try to change the string literals pointed to by the pointers.

So you need to redesign your list. Start from removing the global variable `first` and the pointer to the head node make a local variable in main initializing it by `NULL`. Then change the function `insert` by allocating dynamically memory for a copy of passed to the function string. Rewrite the function `sort` that will swap entire nodes instead of separate data members. 
And for entered strings use character arrays.